# using regex in ruby to change format of date

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm currently scraping the dates of various events from a website. The date is returned as `2015-04-27T20:00+00:00`".

I can use a regular expression to get `2015-04-27` to appear, but am having trouble finding a way to format this date to 27-04-2015, eg `dd-mm-yyyy`.

Currently I have `[/^[^\T]*/]`.

I have searched other posts but to no avail, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not a ruby expert, but there is probably a more easy way to deal with date formats. Take a look here: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using `Date`

```
require 'date'
date = '2015-04-27T20:00+00:00'
puts Date.parse(date).strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you did want to do it with regex though you could use this ...

```
irb(main):019:0> date = '2015-04-27T20:00+00:00'
=> "2015-04-27T20:00+00:00"
irb(main):020:0> date = date.sub(/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)T.*$/,'\3-\2-\1');
irb(main):021:0* date
=> "27-04-2015"
irb(main):022:0>
```